# .mil zone DNS requests does not resolved form Russia

Tags: dns

```
D:\>nslookup.exe

-> server 8.8.8.8
Сервер по умолчанию:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

-> ya.ru
Сервер:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

non-authoritative answer:
Имя:     ya.ru
Addresses:  2a02:6b8::3
          213.180.193.3
          213.180.204.3
          93.158.134.3

-> www.af.mil
Сервер:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Timed out request: google-public-dns-a.google.com
>
```

UPD. Resolving .mil zone from Digtial Ocean virtual host

```
$ nslookup
> www.af.mil
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.af.mil      canonical name = www.af.mil.edgesuite.net.
www.af.mil.edgesuite.net        canonical name = a499.dscb.akamai.net.
Name:   a499.dscb.akamai.net
Address: 2.21.243.59
Name:   a499.dscb.akamai.net
Address: 2.21.243.75
```

now lets switch to Russian public DNS server

```
> server dns.yandex.ru
Default server: dns.yandex.ru
Address: 77.88.8.8#53
Default server: dns.yandex.ru
Address: 2a02:6b8::feed:ff#53
> www.af.mil
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 77.88.8.8, trying next server
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

OOPS !! what happend ???

Comment: It's not just you. It times out from the United States too.

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: Online service DNS lookup 
 DNS lookup – Look up DNS record
IP address or host name:    

Server:
  127.0.0.1

Address:
 127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.af.mil canonical name = www.af.mil.edgesuite.net.
www.af.mil.edgesuite.net canonical name = a499.dscb.akamai.net.
Name:
 a499.dscb.akamai.net

Address:
 195.13.205.24
Name:
 a499.dscb.akamai.net

Address:
 195.13.205.9

Comment: I do. I just tried it! I think the problem is Google DNS though.

Comment: @michaelm How could you possibly know that it doesn't time out from the US if you're in Russia? What makes you think it's just Russia?

Comment: from Amsterdam EU all looks fine too:
# nslookup
> www.af.mil
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.af.mil      canonical name = www.af.mil.edgesuite.net.
www.af.mil.edgesuite.net        canonical name = a499.dscb.akamai.net.
Name:   a499.dscb.akamai.net
Address: 2.21.243.75
Name:   a499.dscb.akamai.net
Address: 2.21.243.59

Comment: I think Google hides .mil resources from Russian users :)) it's vere funny

Comment: You think that Google hides it from me, too?

Comment: I've try also nslookup from Digital Ocean virtual host from Amsterdam and it resolved www.af.mil fine as you can see in log above. So I look for any reason why I can't reslove www.af.mil from hosts in Russia, in MTS net (vere large Russian Internet Provider). At this time I suppose political but not technical reasons, isn't it?